# Hiding content depending on variable value

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, hide, show-hide

I am making a price estimator.

How would correctly write a jQuery function that checks a variable and depending on that amount hides/shows a certain div element accordingly.

So if I had:

a HTML div with the ID 'Answer'

```
<div id="answer">Hide Me</div>

$("#answer")...
```

a variable (this variable would change)

```
var x = 30
```

Now I know the css to hide the div would be:

```
#answer{
visibilty:hidden;
}
```

What would be the correct way to hide the function checking these certain parameters? for example if x > 20 then hide etc

Now I know there will be many ways to do this and they may not require jQuery, please inform me if this is the case. Perhaps it just needs JS. I know there will be many ways to do it not just one so if you have a different way please comment as I am keen to learn.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers

F

Comment: Welcome on SO. You're supposed to show us some code to prove your efforts. This is some easy script, even for a beginner (we're talking a few lines of code max...)

Comment: If that can improve your further contributions, yes please, keep that in mind. I invite you to read the [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page so that you can see this is nothing personnal. The many similar answers from people desperately looking for reputation shouldn't encourage you, although I'm sure it will help in the specific case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Execute this function providing the variable `v`:

```
var checkVar = function(v) {
   var target = $('#answer');
   if (parseInt(v) > 20) {
      target.hide();
   } else {
      target.show();
   }
}
```

For example, if the variable comes form a selection:

```
$('#selectId').on('change', function() {
   checkVar($(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that you can also remove or add a class:

```
$('#answer').removeClass('hide');
$('#answer').addClass('hide');
```

But what you want to do is `$('#answer').hide();` or `$('#answer').show();`

Comment: I personnally prefer the class option as it is not implying inline styles (even generated by JS) and is much more versatile if ever the desired effect needs to be changed.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the CSS. You can do it in jQuery

```
if(x>20){
 $('#answer').hide();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this one

```
   $("#answer").hide();
```

Comment: or use  $("#answer").css("visibility","hidden");

Comment: can also use by create class: .hideDiv{visibilty:hidden;}  and add this class to answer div like this: $("#answer").addClass("hideDiv");

Answer (score 0):

@kapantzak's answer looks good. But keep your logic and style separated and if your not going to use the variable for the actual element twice, I wouldn't make it. So go:

```
var checkVar = function(var) {
   var element = $('#answer');
   if (parseInt(var) > 20) {
      element.addClass('hidden');
   }else{
      element.removeClass('hidden');
   }
}
```

And in your CSS go:

```
#answer.hidden{
 display: none;
}
```

Also, depending on your preference, `display: none;` doesn't display anything of the object whereas `visibility: hidden` hides the object but the space the object was occupying will remain occupied.

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<input id="changingValue">
...
<div id="answer">Hide Me</div>
```

CSS (not mandatory if you check values on loading)

```
#answer{ display:none;}
```

JS

```
var limit = 20;
$(function(){
    $("#changingValue").change(function(){
         if(parseInt($("#changingValue").val())<limit) { $("#answer").show(); }
         else { $("#answer").hide(); }
    });
});
```